# Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook' or one of its dependencies

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to authenticate using facebook's graph api.  I am using this to get an access_token.  I am redirecting to the facebook with the following:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&display={2}&scope={3}", clientId, redirectUrl, display, scope));
```

When the facebook redirects back to my site, I am getting a  *Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook' or one of its dependencies*

When facebook returns, the address looks fine.

```
http://mylocalhost.com/Facebook/oauth-redirect.aspx?code=..........
```

However, IIS/.NET is throwing a configuration error -- *Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook' or one of its dependencies*

```
Line 57:                 <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Line 58:                 
Line 59:                 
Line 60:                 
Line 61:

I confirmed that Facebook.dll and Facebook.Web.dll are in my *bin* folder.

My environment is:

Facebook C# SDK 5.0.3

VS 2010

.NET 4.0

IIS 7 (using to debug)

http://MyLocalhost.com/

Any thoughts on what is not configured properly?

Thanks.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

This may be not the correct answer but I faced error like this in some other project .Try changing the `framework settings`

in the properties of the solution and set it same to the sdk you are using i.e if you are using facebook 4.0 (`dotnet version notsdk version)` then change it from dotnetframework 4.0 client(default in Vs 2010) to 4.0